# error in if statement ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: pandas, if-statement

**I need to add a new column in my dataframe based in a condition from column 3**. 
I receive the error:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
Much appreciated any help!
My file is as follows:

```
2017;Jan;TURKRETAIL;7000007;[ICP None];ClosingBal_Input;Cost;Retail;LocalGAAPInput;C; 14,947.00 
2017;Jan;TURKRETAIL;5103001;[ICP None];ClosingBal_Input;BS_Input;Retail;LocalGAAPInput;C; 90,798.00 
2017;Jan;TURKRETAIL;7000002;[ICP None];ClosingBal_Input;BS_Input;Retail;LocalGAAPInput;D; 8,500.00 
2017;Jan;TURKRETAIL;2769601;[ICP None];NOPRODUCT;Operations;0;LocalGAAPInput;D; 684.00
```

And the Code:

```
import pandas as pd
file_to_open=("C:\\Users\\yannis\\py_script\\py2\\tst1.txt")
file_output=("C:\\Users\\yannis\\py_script\\py2\\tst2.txt")

df = pd.read_csv(file_to_open,sep=";",encoding="utf8",header=None)

df[3] = df[3].astype(str).str.strip()

def f(self):
    if  df[3].str.startswith('2',na=False):
        val = 'Mvmts_NetIncome'
    elif df[3].str.startswith('5',na=False):
        val = 'Other'
        return val
    df[11] = df.apply(f,axis=1)

df.to_csv (file_output,sep=";",encoding="utf8",header=None)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
import pandas as pd
file_to_open=("C:\\Users\\yannis\\py_script\\py2\\tst1.txt")
file_output=("C:\\Users\\yannis\\py_script\\py2\\tst2.txt")

df = pd.read_csv(file_to_open,sep=";",encoding="utf8",header=None)

df[3] = df[3].astype(str).str.strip()

def f(row): #give an argument to f
    if  row[3].str.startswith('2',na=False): #use the argument as row name not df
        val = 'Mvmts_NetIncome'
    elif row[3].str.startswith('5',na=False):
        val = 'Other'
        return val

df[11] = df.apply(f,axis=1) #this shouldn't be inside the function

df.to_csv (file_output,sep=";",encoding="utf8",header=None)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I get the following error:if  row[3].str.startswith('2',na=False): #use the argument as row name not df
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply a function to each row, then the function must receive the row series, but each element of the `row_serie[3]` is a string, so there is no need to user `str` method:

```
def f(row_serie):
    val = ''
    if  row_serie[3].startswith('2'): 
         val = 'Mvmts_NetIncome'
    elif row_serie[3].startswith('5'):
        val = 'Other'
    return val

df[11] = df.apply(f,axis=1)
```

Consider adding a default value in case the column 3 does not start with 2 nor 5.